# In IntelliJ IDEA, how to disable the hints that lists the overloaded methods and parameters?

Tags: intellij-idea, overloading

Those ones :

[image: hint over a method]

They appear during code writing in case I've written the name of a method that is overloaded.

Those don't seem to by inlay hints : I've disabled inlay hints about parameter names and types, and these hints still show up.

I know what method I want to use, I don't need that frame that hides my code.

How can I disable them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable it in the `Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion | Show the parameter info popup in ... milliseconds`.

See here for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#configure-parameter-info-popup